# Extracting a part of the string which matches a pattern Makefile

Tags: makefile

If I have to extract a part of the string, what should be the command to do that in Makefile.

Consider that I need a number which is a part of the pwd.

```
$(shell pwd) -- /xxx/www/yyy22/zzz
```

How would I extract the 22 from the pwd ?

Comment: How do you want it to do ?

Comment: What is the way to do it. Is there a function in makefile or some other way by which i can accomplish that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not exact: what if there are more than one set of numbers in the string?  Do you want them all?  Just the first one?  Just the last one?

In any event, you can't do this with built-in make functions.  You'll have to use the shell; for example to return all the numbers in the string:

```
numbers := $(shell pwd | sed 's/[^0-9]//g')
```

Comment: thanks.. I know exactly what the format of the string is going to be like. So there is going to be only one instance. I should have added that.